# Git: Ignore merging a specific file from one remote, still track it in Git repo

Tags: git, gitignore, git-remote

I have a repo "foobar" set up that acts as a template for spinning up new projects. (It has a lot of files that don't change from project to project very often.) It has a README.md file describing it as a template. To spin up a new project, I clone this repository, keeping an upstream origin "foobar". (git clone -o foobar)

The project is then given a new origin on github. The rationale is that I can run `git pull foobar` to merge in any changes from this "foobar" repo to any project I've spun up off of it.

Foobar contains a script that renames the base "README.md" to "README.dist.md" and creates a new README.md specific to the new project.

When I run `git pull foobar` I always get a merge conflict since it is different. Is there a way to pull all commits in and *ignore* the README.md file? Note I still need the file to be tracked separately in the project repo, and the foobar repo.

Comment: In foobar, call the file README.dist.md. Symlink or copy a README.md (in foobar), but don't add it into the project. Now spun-off projects will inherit even README changes into their .dist copies, and you can individually decide which you want to pull into individual projects. This probably isn't the solution you were looking for (I don't know if one exists), but it can work :)

Comment: Edit: Oh wait, I guess your point of calling it README.md in foobar was that github displays it. And you probably can't have a file in github that isn't part of the repo... Maybe use their wiki for the template or something? :)